# Short story that reminds me of 65 movie premise

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, prehistoric

Read this one decades ago, and could have been written earlier. Could have been in an Asimov anthology as I was going through a pretty major sci fi/short story phase.

At any rate, it’s about the crew of an exploring space ship that crash lands on a planet that is described as very like prehistoric earth. They fight and struggle with various critters using their advanced weapons, and eventually use up all their ammo and technology. It ends with one male and one female character making their way in the new world with fur clothing and stone weapons, ostensibly the first humans.

If I had to guess I’d say I read it in the late ‘70s and likely written in the ‘50s or ‘60s. I read so many short story collections and anthologies during that period that I have no idea what else may have been in there. I know it’s not a lot of help, but the trailer for [the film 65](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65_(film)) made me sure it was based on that story, but I couldn’t find anything credited.

Thanks in advance…

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It would help if you could narrow down the decade on this, 70s, 80s, 90s...  Any idea what other stories might have been in the same anthology?

Comment: As TVTropes mentions, the Adam & Eve plot is *extremely* common, and that's not including the huge number of stories with this "twist" that were rejected. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AdamAndEvePlot

Comment: Thanks you guys, if I had to guess I’d say I read it in the late ‘70s and likely written in the ‘50s or ‘60s. I read so many short story collections and anthologies during that period that I have no idea what else may have been in there. I know it’s not a lot of help, but the trailer for 65 made me sure it was based on that story.

Comment: Your description sounds similar to David Gerrold's 1981 novel "Death Beast", and also the 1977 movie "Planet of Dinosaurs".

Comment: "Genesis" by H. Beam Piper? A spaceship from Mars crashes on prehistoric earth, and the survivors have to spend their lives here. It follows them walking for years, and ends with something like "we are the men from Mars". There are more than 2 people left at the end though.

Comment: Sue!! That’s the one!

Comment: I was able to read the whole story here - https://scifistories.com/s/414/genesis - can’t believe I was able to track this down (with lots of help). The fact that a lot of my offerings were wrong certainly didn’t help, but in my defense , the fact that it’s been 50 years or so is my only excuse. And it was Piper! Hard to believe I only (knowingly) found him recently, and that after reading Scalzi’s rewrite of Little Fuzzy. Thank you all again…

Comment: @Matt - shanu wrote this up as a proper answer; would you be so kind as to accept it?

Comment: I almost suggested *Genesis*, but it didn't seem like a close enough match. ;) FWIW, there are quite a few H Beam Piper stories on Project Gutenberg.  https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/author/8301

Answer (score 3):

This question was solved in the comments section by @Sueelleker, and the OP has verified that it is indeed the answer.

The short story's name is [Genesis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/160597742X), written by H Beam Piper and was published in 1951 in a magazine.

The plot synopsis reads -

> Was this ill-fated expedition the end of a proud, old race—or the beginning of a new one? There are strange gaps in our records of the past. We find traces of man-like things—but, suddenly, man appears, far too much developed to be the "next step" in a well-linked chain of evolutionary evidence. Perhaps something like the events of this story furnishes the answer to the riddle.

The short story can be read on [SciFi-Stories](https://scifistories.com/s/414/genesis).

Comment: Maybe first ping @Sueelleker to see if they want to write up an answer?

Comment: @Joachim, I was actually online when they answered the question in the comments and let it be coz it's their answer, but today when I woke up and saw 12 hours had passed by and still no answer I decided to answer the question

Comment: but surely if @sueelleker asks me to delete my answer I would.

Comment: No, that's fine. I tend not to post an answer unless I'm 100% sure it's right, that's why I posted it as a comment. Glad it was what you were looking for.

Comment: *Genesis* is  not a "Book". It is a work of short fiction, first published in a magazine. https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?61690